# Do not create an error page when a page does not exist

Tags: php

I have a domain which I want every attempted url after https://www.example.com/someFolder/ to not give an error but instead give a php page.

For example, I do not have a somefolder/abc.php file but going there will run a process.php file instead and display it there.

I have attempted to modify the 404 page as the process.php but that also modifies the example.com/ error page which I do not want.

It would be great if I do not need to modify/add a file at the root directory

PS. adding a .htaccess to the somefolder folder does work somewhat but then the url shows somefolder/404.php and not somefolder/abc.php

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache (or something else)?

Comment: Apache/2.2.15 (Oracle)

Comment: you could try [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).

Comment: @funk forty niner how would i archive such please give an example if you can, i am interested in an answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned that I could turn somefolder into somefolder.php and use the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] to make all pages exist.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your 404 page as you did putting php script there but check in php if the url that was requested was directory or not. Depending on that make an appropriate action

```
<?php

$url = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];

// check if requested url was ending with slash
$pattern = '#\/$#';
$result = preg_match($pattern, $url);

if ($result === 1) {
    //request was to directory suffixed with slash

    //do your php code for custom 404

    die; //end the page generation
}

?>

request was not to directory ending with slash
put html of regular 404 page here or leave it blank
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that can only be done, in the general case, by using the `.htaccess` file, and redirecting every request like this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

After that, you can use `$_SERVER`, `$_SESSION`, and other global variables in index.php to decide how to handle a 404 error (i.e., you can implement here how to define what a 404 is, etc.).

For instance, `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` will be able to tell you what URL was requested, and you can use a combination of `file_exists()` and other calls, to determine if you want to display a full 404, search results, a redirect, or simply to display the results of another script.

This works for example.com/somefolder/, example.com/some/other/folder/, and example.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/, etc..